# *Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins Randomly Activating While Bootup and Operation of OS*

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio, raspbian-wheezy

not strictly a programming question but found no other solutions on the web. Using the Pi i have followed the diagram below to control two motors in an old rc tank chassis.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpnD5.jpg)

Ive gotten all the hardware correct, i.e. H-Bridge etc but what happens is the motor connected to pins 7&11 (4 and 17 for BCM mode) just starts spinning.

My question is are any of these pins set to autimatically transmit a signal on power up or is this an OS issue. Any help would be much appreciated thx :).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please insert your image directly here instead of providing a link (this is considered as good manners here). Also, you probably would like to ask at http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.